# Quarkus integration tests are not picking test properties

Tags: gradle, apache-kafka, quarkus, testcontainers, smallrye-reactive-messaging

I have a quarkus application which consumes from kafka topic, I have written kafka consumer integration tests using testContainers. but I am facing issue while running the tests, **it picks the real brokers url which are saved in my .zshrc file  for kafka-bootstrap-servers property not the localhost**, even though I defined the test properties.

This is the application properties.

```
kafka:
  bootstrap:
    servers: ${KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS:localhost:9092}

  security:
    protocol: SASL_SSL
  sasl:
    mechanism: SCRAM-SHA-512
  jaas:
    config: org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="${KAFKA_CONSUMER_USERNAME}"
    password="${KAFKA_CONSUMER_PASSWORD}";


"%test":
   kafka:
     bootstrap:
       servers: kafka:9092
     security:
       protocol: PLAINTEXT
     sasl:
       mechanism: PLAIN
```

I have used QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager to set the kafka property as well.

```
public class KafkaResource implements QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager {


    private static KafkaContainer kafkaContainer;

    private static String bootstrapServers;

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> start() {
   
        kafkaContainer = new KafkaContainer(DockerImageName.parse("confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest"))
                .withKraft();
        kafkaContainer.start();
        bootstrapServers = kafkaContainer.getBootstrapServers();
        return Map.of("kafka.bootstrap.servers", 
        kafkaContainer.getBootstrapServers());
   
        return Collections.emptyMap();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        kafkaContainer.stop();
    }

    public static String getBootstrapServers() {
       return bootstrapServers;
    }
```

}

consumer integration tests:

```
@QuarkusTest
@QuarkusTestResource(KafkaResource.class)
class ConsumerTest {

  @InjectSpy
  EventConsumer eventConsumer;

  @Test
  void testConsumer() throws InvalidProtocolBufferException, InterruptedException {
    String eventId = "sport1234";
    Event event = Event.newBuilder().setEventId(eventId)
            .build();
    produceTestMessage(event);

    Mockito.verify(eventConsumer, timeout(5000)).consumeState(event.toByteArray());
    System.out.println("Number of invocations: " + Mockito.mockingDetails(eventConsumer).getInvocations().size());
  }

  private void produceTestMessage(Event event) {
    // Create a Kafka producer configuration
    String kafkaBootstrapServers = KafkaResource.getBootstrapServers();
    Properties producerProps = new Properties();
    producerProps.put("bootstrap.servers", kafkaBootstrapServers);
    producerProps.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    producerProps.put("value.serializer", "com.org.events.EventProtoKafkaSerializer");

    try (Producer<String, Event> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(producerProps)) {
        ProducerRecord<String, Event> record = new ProducerRecord<>("test_topic", event.getEventId(), event);
        producer.send(record).get(); // Wait for the message to be sent
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error producing test message", e);
    }
 }
```

}

**dependencies:**

```
implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-reactive-messaging-kafka'
testImplementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5'
testImplementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5-mockito'
testImplementation 'io.rest-assured:rest-assured'
testImplementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-jacoco'
testImplementation 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.24.2'
testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter:1.19.3'
testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:mysql:1.19.3'
testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:kafka:1.19.3'
```

***Now my consumer integration tests works fine if I remove KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS property from .zshrc file. but when I keep it tests tries to connect to dev server not the localhost which I defined in test profile and setting in KafkaResource file as well.***

What am I missing??

Comment: That `%test%` config has incorrect indentation. The `servers:` key must be under the `bootstrap:`. Now, those are on the same level.

Comment: @zforgo no indentation isn't the problem.

Comment: There are serveral problems with this question.  The indentation just one of them. E.g. the mentioned test is not an integration test as the title was described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried removing all the kafka related properties from application properties file but still It was picking the brokers from KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS key in .zshrc file.

Then I changed the ***KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS*** to ***KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_DEV*** then all tests passed.

I think it was converting ***KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS*** to ***kafka.bootstrap.servers*** which is kafka's real property to set the brokers in tests and system properties have higher precedence over others.

So changing the variable solved my issue.